# Adding page border to HTML/PDF generation in Node/Puppeteer/Handlebars

Tags: css, node.js, pdf, handlebars.js, puppeteer

I am using Node and Puppeteer to generate a PDF that uses a handlebars template. All is working as expected.

My only question is: how does one add border padding to the document, so that, if the document runs over multiple pages, the content doesn't go right up to the very edge of the page? Is there a style element I can use?

See my handlebars template below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PDF Result Template</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      margin: auto;
      padding: 30px;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 13px;
      font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica';
      color: #555;
    }

    .top-heading {
      margin-bottom: -20px;
      color: red;
    }

    .box {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .table-box {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }

    .left-box {
      float: left;
      min-width: 25%;
      max-width: 25%;
      margin-top: -20px;
    }

    .right-box {
      float: right;
      min-width: 75%;
      max-width: 75%;
    }

    .one-quarter {
      border: #ccc thin solid;
      max-width: 25%;
    }

    .half {
      border: #ccc thin solid;
      max-width: 50%;
    }

    .three-quarter {
      border: #ccc thin solid;
      min-width: 75%;
      max-width: 75%;
    }

    .full {
      border: #ccc thin solid;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .highlighted {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .flat-line {
      border: none;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .header {
      clear: both;
      margin-top: 120px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .centered {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .details-cell {
      padding: 0 8px;
    }

    .notes-table {
      margin-top: 20px;
      min-width: 100%;
    }

    .goal-heading {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .signature {
      margin-top: 10px;
      min-width: 100px;
      max-width: 100px;
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      // Other code
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think so, no - because the paging is not a CSS issue per se. I'm not aware of a an HTML attribute I can use to apply CSS to in this case, to handle adding border padding to the edge of each page that ends up being generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access styling for the page like so:

```
@page {
  margin: 10px 0; 
}
```

So by adding the above to the handlebars template you're able to add the desired `10px` of margin to the top and bottom of the document.